# What is this building you are seeing/viewing on the map - which is correct?

Tags: word-choice

> What is this building you are **seeing** on the map?
>   What is this building you are **viewing** on the map?

Comment: I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

Comment: Typically I would just say "what building are you **looking at** [on the map]?"

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain what you're trying to express? I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your sample question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is (more) correct, though still sounds a bit foreign to my ear.

**Seeing** is more passive, while **viewing** is more active. You wouldn't "see" the television show, you would "view" or "watch" the television show. Noticing the building is, in this case, more passive than actively watching the building.

There is, however, an interesting distinction here. While you **see** the building on the map, you would NOT "see the map" - you would instead **view** (or more colloquially, **look at**) the map.

---

In your case, I would slightly reword the question to "What is **the** building you **see** on the map?"

The first change should make sense. You don't know the specific building that the person is seeing, therefore "this" doesn't really fit. In more advanced usage, "this" has other implications (I can imagine a regular person saying "what is *this* magic you speak of," if a wizard were trying to explain magic to somebody who didn't know what it is - it adds a touch of skepticism). You are talking about a specific building though, so "the" is chosen over "a."

The second change, going from "seeing" to "see" is harder for me to explain. The easiest way I can come up with right now is saying that you see something once. It isn't really a process that is taking place. "John sees the building." You would never say "John is seeing the building."

Comment: Disagree with:
> You wouldn't "see" the television show, you would "view" or "watch" the television show.
"Did you see the game last night?"  "Did you watch the game last night?" are quite interchangeable.

Comment: Alex K, thank you so much! I just noticed that you used "seeing the building", though :) -- "You don't know the specific building that the person is seeing, therefore..." Please, explain.

Comment: @VictorBazarov For the past, that's a valid point. For the present, you would NEVER hear somebody say over the phone, "Yeah, I'm seeing the game." Watch is much more ntural when the action is going on. Since in the present watch is the better option, and in the past, they are interchangable, I think it's a safe rule, especially for somebody learning, just to stick with "watch."

Comment: @Rada The best way I can explain it would be that when you see a building on a map, you are noticing it. You aren't actively watching it. If I'm watching a building, I'm actively looking at it, not just noticing it.

Comment: @AlexK Thanks a lot! So, now I'm dealing with "seeing", "viewing", "watching" and "looking at"... :)